# Stopping a service passed through Notification Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-activity, android-view

In my app I have a notification in the task bar and when clicked it starts a new Activity view   of my program. However when I try and use the stop button to stop my service from within this view, nothing happens. I am assuming when I press the notification button that it does not keep my ACTIVITY linked with the service.

When my app is first opened, the service is started by using the Intent below:

```
Intent svc = new Intent(this, StreamService.class);
startService(svc);
```

Then in the service:

```
//Intent passed when notification is selected.
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
```

Any idea how to link back to my running service? Or perhaps bring the original activity/view back to the front when the notification is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Intent that you can attach to the notification should have a service intent, with a specific action. In your service's onStart method, you can check it's a close action, and then you can call stopSelf().

Comment: Well the action I would like is to open up the last view. Stopping the service is just something they can do from within that view.(The service is playing music) I am afraid I am still unsure how to use your advice. The stop playing button just isn't working because it is not linked with the service anymore. Or so I assume.

Comment: Notification -> Starts activity, Activity -> Closes the service (Directly or through intent).

Comment: I am very sorry, I had an old if statement that was disabling some functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If the Activity you are opening from the notification is part of the same application as the service, then it is be able to stop the service.  Try to use:

```
Intent svc = new Intent(this, StreamService.class);
stopService(svc);
```